# Story with a white cover about a girl that falls in love with werewolf

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, werewolf, fairy

I read the book in middle school, about ten years ago. It's about a girl that moves and falls in love with a werewolf. I remember that fairies (fae) were involved and the cover was white. It's not Shiver.

Comment: The details in your question are incredible sparse and I imagine there's quite a few possibilities. Take a look at this [list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337) and see if you can add in any more points from the checklist there. Such as was it a novel/short story? Any other details about the plot? The setting? The relevance of the fairies?

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Twilight-Saga-White-Editions-Breaking/dp/B005X65Z8S

Comment: This is too terse to be answered sensibly. I can identify ten examples just by looking at Goodreads.

Comment: Just to be explicit on the matter, if you [edit] more details in, the question will be marked as potentially reopenable. :)